# How to call a method when routing to a template in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service, route-provider

How to call a method from a service when routing to a template in AngularJS?

```
wikiApp.config(['$routeProvider', 'faqService', 'newsService', 
  function($routeProvider, faqService, newsService) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/hjem',{
        templateUrl: 'partials/homeContent.html',
    resolve: {
      newsService.setChosenStory("");
      faqService.setChosenFAQ("");
    }
 })
```

this is not correct? :S

Comment: I have no idea what resolve does, btw

Comment: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolve is used to pass additional parameters to controller, for example:

```
$routeProvider
.when('/a', {
    templateUrl: '/tmpl',
    controller: 'myCtrl',
    resolve: {
        someParameter: function(){
            return 'konichiva';
        }
    }
})
.when('/b', {
    templateUrl: '/tmpl',
    controller: 'myCtrl',
    resolve: {
        someParameter: function(){
            return 'vatashiva';
        }
    }
});
```

in `myCtrl`:

```
wikiApp.controller('myCtrl', function(someParameter){
    // if path is "/a" then "konichiva" will be logged
    // else if path is "/b" then "vatashiva" will be logged
    console.log(someParameter);
});
```

Comment: Cool, and i can send it to services as well? or not?

Comment: You can use your service in controller like this: `wikiApp.controller('myCtrl', function(someParameter, faqService, newsService){...`